# How to use signify in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to do a remote desktop connection between Ubuntu desktop and another Ubuntu system. I want to develop an application so it is necessary to use shell command.

```
ssh -X or -Y username@server_ip
```

I know this command is for trusted and untrusted connection between two systems but here username is necessary for connection so it is necessary to ask username and password to each user for connection. so I have created a bash file for getting input from the user. its name myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
read -p 'Username: ' uservar
read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
sleep 10
```

and I want to use this variable value in another file. I wrote below code and file name terminal.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash<br>
xterm -e /file_path/myscript.sh
sshpass -p $passvar ssh -X $uservar@$remote_ip /usr/bin/xfce4-session
```

but this code is not working. I want myscript.sh user input value in terminal.sh file. one person suggests me to use signify. how to use signify here? Can anyone suggest a solution? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why just have single script and read username/password before passing to ssh?

Comment: in login manage, I need a terminal and with a use of this terminal, the user can enter their password and username. this username and password, I need in another file for ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should set-up public/private key authentication with ssh. Anything else is a hack to get the same result.

In this case, you have to store the credentials (uid/pw) somewhere to be able to use them in your second script. That could be:

```
#!/bin/bash 
read -p 'Username: ' uservar
read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
```

and call as `. myscript.sh`, or store them somewhere in a file for use (which is security-wise a little issue).

If you really cannot set-up your p/p-keys, you should probably put (as Inian suggests) put the prompting in the same script..